# Got error C2062: type 'int' unexpected with code from textbook

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers

Trying to use basic pointer feature to display some numbers that entered by user. However, the displaying is in error while the input is OK.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "How many integers you wish to enter? ";
int InputNums = 0;
cin >> InputNums;

int* pNumbers = new int [InputNums]; // allocate requested integers
int* pCopy = pNumbers;

cout<<"Successfully allocated memory for "<<InputNums<< " integers"<<endl;
for(int Index = 0; Index < InputNums; ++Index)
{
cout << "Enter number "<< Index << ": ";
cin >> *(pNumbers++);
}

cout << "Displaying all numbers input: " << endl;

for(int Index = 0, int* pCopy = pNumbers; Index < InputNums; ++Index) 
    cout << *(pCopy++) << " ";

cout << endl;

// done with using the pointer? release memory
delete[] pNumbers;

return 0;
}
```

Error from the line for(int Index = 0, int* pCopy = pNumbers; Index < InputNums; ++Index).

The code actually from textbook "teaching c++ in 21 days", nothing changed.

Please help, thanks a lot.

Comment: That's not valid syntax.  You can't declare variables with different types in a for statement like that.

Comment: You are 100% sure that the textbook actually has this line: `for(int Index = 0, int* pCopy = pNumbers; Index < InputNums; ++Index)`? If so, get a new book! (Also, how is it expecting to delete `pNumbers` once it's out of scope?!)

Comment: Yes, 100% copied. could you please explain why it is not valid? new to CPP, sorry to bother.

Comment: @user2247342 Is it this Sams Teach Yourself C++ In One Hour a Day? If so, your code differs from the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in your book is bad. It should be like this (the code also bad, but here is the code should be):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "How many integers you wish to enter? ";
    int InputNums = 0;
    cin >> InputNums;

    int* pNumbers = new int [InputNums]; // allocate requested integers
    int* pCopy = pNumbers;

    cout<<"Successfully allocated memory for "<<InputNums<< " integers"<<endl;
    for(int Index = 0; Index < InputNums; ++Index)
    {
        cout << "Enter number "<< Index << ": ";
        cin >> *(pCopy++); //use pCopy to 'walk' the array
    }

    cout << "Displaying all numbers input: " << endl;
    pCopy = pNumber; //reset pCopy
    for(int Index = 0; Index < InputNums; ++Index) 
        cout << *(pCopy++) << " ";

    cout << endl;

    // done with using the pointer? release memory
    delete[] pNumbers; //pNumbers must still point to the address returned in line 10

    return 0;
}
```

I wonder who is the author of the book.

Answer (score 0):

Change `cin >> *(pNumbers++);` to `cin >> *(pCopy++);`

Change `int* pCopy = pNumbers` to `*pCopy = pNumbers`

That should do the trick. However, this example is ugly as hell. I would recommend you changing your textbook.

Comment: Just figured out, deleted int* pCopy = pNumbers   in   for(int Index = 0, int* pCopy = pNumbers; Index < InputNums; ++Index)

Comment: If you only deleted int* pCopy = pNumbers from the for statement the line delete[] pNumbers is incorrect. It may not throw an error but it's still incorrect.

Comment: really? OMG, cost me 29USD this book....you mean  delete[] pNumbers out of scope? thanks

Comment: delete[] should be called with the original pointer returned by new[]. However, in this case it's called with pNumbers, which used to be what new[] returned, but then was modified (with ++ operator). A simple error.

Comment: And yes, the example from the book looks really terrible, even when it's corrected it still looks miserable. I don't know this book, but it looks like it doesn't teach good programming style.

Comment: This statement is incorrect:
"Change int* pCopy = pNumbers to *pCopy = pNumbers".
It should be pCopy = pNumbers.

Comment: @dragon135 you can't put such a statement inside of a for statement. The way it is now, it declares a new `pCopy` pointer that overshadows the previous one. If you don't add the `*` in front of `pCopy`, it will be declared as an int and not a pointer to an int. If you want `pCopy = pNumbers`, it should be outside of the for statement and it would pertain to the original pCopy variable. This would be a cleaner and better solution, however I aimed at minimal modification of the OP's code.

Comment: I thought you want to move the statement before the loop, because the new variable shadows the previous variable (bad practice considering the previous variable is not loop variable).

Comment: your solution is better, though still this code could be written much better. I'd use *(pNumbers + Index) (or pNumbers[Index]) without messing with pCopy.